# Als mit Konjunktiv II (Irreale Vergleiche)

Tags: subjunctive, perfect-tense

Ich habe ein Problem über „hätten gehabt“ und nur „hätten“. Hier gibt es einige Beispiele. Kann mir das bitte jemand klar erklären?

*Schreiben Sie Sätze mit „als“ und Konjunktiv II.*

> 1. Die Wohnung sah aus, ...(die Bewohner, sie, fluchtartig verlassen haben)
> 2. Auf dem Tisch standen drei Tassen, ... (ein Treffen, stattgefunden haben)
> 3. Die Möbel lagen kreuz und quer auf dem Boden, ... (ein Kampf, stattgefunden haben)

**Meine Antworten**:

> 1. Die Wohnung sah aus, als hätten die Bewohner sie fluchtartig verlassen gehabt.
> 2. Auf dem Tisch standen drei Tassen, als hätte ein Treffen stattgefunden gehabt.
> 3. Die Möbel lagen kreuz und quer auf dem Boden, als hätte ein Kampf stattgefunden gehabt.

Aber die echten Antworten sind alle ohne „gehabt“. Warum denn? Ich verstehe, dass alle Sätze Vergangenheit sind. Dann muss es doch zusammen mit „gehabt“ gebildet werden, oder?

**Die korrekten Antworten**:

> 1. Die Wohnung sah aus, als hätten die Bewohner sie fluchtartig verlassen.
> 2. Auf dem Tisch standen drei Tassen, als hätte ein Treffen stattgefunden.
> 3. Die Möbel lagen kreuz und quer auf dem Boden, als hätte ein Kampf stattgefunden.

Answer (score 6):

Dein Problem hat eigentlich nichts mit dem Konjunktiv II zu tun. Du versuchst Verben, die bereits im Perfekt stehen, *nochmal* ins Perfekt zu setzen, und das ist nicht erlaubt.

Das Perfekt wird gebildet aus Partizip Perfekt + **sein**/**haben** (das Hilfsverb kann weiter konjugiert werden).

Deine Beispiele sind bereits im Perfekt:

> verlassen **haben**
>
> stattgefunden **haben**

Wie gesagt, das "haben" kann weiter konjugiert werden, das ergibt dann die korrekten Lösungen:

> Sie **haben** verlassen. -> Sie **hätten** verlassen.
>
> Es **hat** stattgefunden. -> Es **hätte** stattgefunden.

Die Perfektbildung ein zweites Mal auszuführen ergibt dagegen keinen Sinn:

> Sie **haben**(1) verlassen.
> -> *Falsch:* Sie **haben**(2) verlassen **gehabt**(1).
> -> *Falsch:* Sie **hätten**(2) verlassen **gehabt**(1).
>
> Es **hat**(1) stattgefunden.
> -> *Falsch:* Es **hat**(2) stattgefunden **gehabt**(1).
> -> *Falsch:* Es **hätte**(2) stattgefunden **gehabt**(1).

Dein zusätzlich eingefügtes "gehabt" wäre das Partizip des "äußeren" Perfekts, aber selbst nur ein Hilfsverb des "inneren" Perfekts und damit redundant.

(Die Satzstellung unterscheidet sich natürlich in Haupt- und Nebensätzen.)

---

Vielleicht nochmal zur Verdeutlichung der Fall, in dem "haben" als Vollverb auftritt:

> Er sah aus,...(er, Glück **gehabt haben**)

Richtig:

> Er sah aus, als **hätte** er Glück **gehabt**.

Deine Variante (falsch):

> Er sah aus, als **hätte** er Glück **gehabt gehabt**.

Comment: In der Tat existiert jedoch eine solche Form, das sog."doppelte Perfekt" - https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt in der Umgangssprache. Insofern würde ich von der Aussage Abstand nehmen, das sei "falsch". Es entspricht nur einem bestimmten Register nicht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ja, durchaus. Hier ging es aber offensichtlich um eine Aufgabe, da bringt Umgangssprache einen nicht unbedingt weiter.

Answer (score 4):

Schauen wir uns mal den Indikativ an:

> Die Bewohner haben die Wohnung fluchtartig verlassen.

Das ist Perfekt. Es ist also bereits Vergangenheit, ein "gehabt" wird dabei nicht benötigt.

Jetzt den Konjunktiv II:

> Die Bewohner hätten die Wohnung fluchtartig verlassen.

Ebenso Perfekt, jetzt mit dem Hilfsverb "haben" im Konjunktiv II. Auch hier ist kein "gehabt" nötig, um die Vergangenheit auszudrücken.

Es gilt: Mit "haben" als Hilfsverb + Partizip Perfekt des Vollverbs wird bereits (als Perfekt) Vergangenheit ausgedrückt. Ein "gehabt" ist dafür nicht nötig.